# I want to use TuProlog in my Android Project

Tags: java, android, prolog, tuprolog

How I can make an Android Project using tuProlog like Api
I have benn trying it but I couldn't 
I have this error:

> Could not find class 'alice.tuprolog.Theory', referenced from method....

Answer (score 1):

In your Project Properties, check
Java BuildPath -> Order and Export
that your tuProlog library is checked.
I had the same problem when trying to use a Java library, hope that it helps.

Comment: I had this same problem, and it was solved by this answer. I use Eclipse for my PC build, in a cross platform Android and PC project, so I expected that if it worked in PC, it would work in Android. While indeed the jar was in the build path, even if on PC it was "checked", on Android it may not be case.